# BIRT Report - Multiline text underlined to the full width

Tags: report, birt

I'm trying to create a report with a layout as shown in the picture. The value of each field is underlined to the full width of the report. If it occupies more than one line each line is underlined. And there is also a short comment under the first line explaining the meaning of the field (shown in parentheses).

When we faced the same problem using JasperReports we had to create a custom component for that purpose. Does anyone know what the solution in BIRT might look like?[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible with BIRT.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking, but I was hoping perhaps this could be achieved with javascript or something...

Comment: You could create a GridLayout or Table and make the border or the cell bolt. It will look like an underlined form field.

Comment: It will but what if the text is longer than one line?

Comment: Exactly that's the problem! I thought of the border myself and that's why I didn't propose this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to calculate the line wrapping yourself, eg. converting your long text into a series of single lines.
Say you find a way to do this in a scripted data set, using the long text as an input.
You could then use a table item to render these single lines in the layout; using the bottom border to create the underlines (or possible an empty extra detail row with a top border and a height of 2pt to create nice line spacing).

Now how would this scripted data set look like?
I think when you study the source code of BIRT, you'll probably somewhere find a utility function that calculates the width (in whatever units) of a given text in a given font and size. Maybe this is also somewhere inside java.awt or inside iText (com.lowagie.text).

Then it *is* possible to call this function from inside Java Script and - with more or less logic - to use this as a basis for your scripted data set. But I think this will take a few hours to code.

If you manage to do this, it'd be nice if you post the solution here.